# How to Diagnose Silverlight Visual Problems

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have silverlight4 code like this,

```
<controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
    <telerik:RadComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

This is simplifying the problem somewhat, but essentially if I set IsBusy to 'true' while I am loading some data, and then set it to 'false' the RadComboBox disables and enables correctly as expected.

If I compile my application and release it to IIS the RadComboBox disables when I set IsBusy to 'true' but then it never enables again after  I set IsBusy to 'false'.

I can't debug it in the normal sense of running VS and starting it on my machine. I have a couple of ideas that would show me more info, but cannot get either to work.

1) I tried to attach a VS debugger to IE running the instance of the application in IIS. The breakpoints I added dissapeared and it said that 'symbols were not loaded'. Perhaps this is because this is a release version of the software and not debug?

2) I tried to use Silverlight Spy to work out what was going on. Unlike snoop I was not able to see what set the IsEnabled property. For instance was it inherited, or was it set in a viewmodel, or directly on the control, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I change it to this it works,

```
<controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
    <telerik:RadComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
</controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

I.e. removed 'Mode=TwoWay' from the RadComboBox binding. Must be a bug in either the telerik control or the BusyIndicator control. I cannot explain it any other way.